# to know if 3 points makes Equilateral triangle

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, geometry

I don't know if i ask this question in right place but i was too desperate and couldn't find any solution for my problem , i have 2 classes Point And Line and i want to write e triangle class and i want to know if 3 lines makes equilateral triangle or not and approve it in my triangle class how can i do it?

here is my point class:

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y; 
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("X: {0} Y:{1}",X,Y);
    }
}
```

here is my line class:

```
class Line
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }
    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(End.X - Start.X, 2) + Math.Pow(End.Y - Start.Y, 2));
        }
    }

    public Line(Point start,Point end)
    {
        Start=start;
        End = end;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Start Point X: {0} Y: {1} End Point X: {2} Y: {3}"
            ,Start.X,Start.Y,End.X,End.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Calculate the lengths of each side, and see if they're the same. Because of floating point inaccuracies, you should allow some tolerance in the equality checks.

Comment: @Barmar How can i be sure if its Triangle? thats my problem i can find out the triangle kind

Comment: If you have 3 points, it always makes a triangle.

Comment: Get the ends of the 3 lines, and see if there are 3 pairs that are equal.

Comment: A triangle has 3 points, not three lines. Get rid of the Line class to avoid confusion. Also, use PointF for better accuracy for equilateral triangles.

Comment: To be precise, it really is a LineSegment and not a Line.  I would think you would extend your thinking and have a Triangle class that would be constructed based on 3-points.  The Triangle class would create 3 LineSegments.  If all 3 LineSegments are the same length, then it is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: A triangle is not made up of any 3 lines, but rather 3 non-colinear, distinct points.

Answer (score 4):

you need to write a method in the Line class to calculate the length of the current line. Remember that a negative length is the same as a positive ;)

Once you have this method, to get you the length of a line, you need to check that the 3 lines of the triangle are all equal. If they are, it is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: As an optimisation: there's no point calculating the actual length: you can compare the **squared** lengths (i.e. don't take the square-root) - which is both faster and less prone to rounding issues